# Is there a builtin function to turn selective Echos off?

Tags: debugging

Suppose I have a code block

```
EchoOff[CompoundExpression[
    ...,
    Echo[...,"echo 1",f],
    Echo[...,"echo 2",g],
    ...
]]
```

Is there a function `EchoOff` that can be wrapped around an expression to turn off the output of all `Echo` encountered?

Moreover is there something like turning selective echos off? For example,

`EchoOff[expr,{1,4}]` turns off the first and fourth `Echo` encountered in the expression.

Or simply if the `Echo` can be marked as 1,2,... and then `EchoOff` can target them with their mark?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `` GeneralUtilities`DisableEcho ``:

```
expr1; Echo[x = 1 + 1]; 
 GeneralUtilities`DisableEcho[ Echo[y = 1 + 2] ; Echo[z = 1 + 3]];Echo[w = 1 + 4]; expr2
```

[image]

```
z + y
```

> 7

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[EchoOff];
SetAttributes[EchoOff, HoldFirst];
EchoOff[code_] := Block[{Echo},
   Echo[c_, bla___] := c;
   code
   ];
```

Then:

```
EchoOff[
 CompoundExpression[1, Echo[1, "echo 1", f], Echo[2, "echo 2", g], 2]
 ]
```

> 2

You can do that selectively by label with

```
EchoOff[code_, blacklist_] := Unevaluated[code] /. Table[
    With[{label = b},
     HoldPattern[Echo[c_, label, bla___]] :> Unevaluated[c]
     ],
    {b, blacklist}
    ];

EchoOff[
 CompoundExpression[1, Echo[1, "echo 1", f], Echo[2, "echo 2", g], 
  2],
 {"echo 1"}
 ]
```

> echo 2 g[2]
>
> 2